# How to configure persistent storage for Apache Ignite cache?

Tags: java, ignite

I'm trying to configure persistent storage for Apache Ignite, so that my IgniteCache instance won't lose data on app restart. My setup is a local one-node cluster started from my code like this:

```
IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();
cfg.setWorkDirectory("C:\\ignite");

// Ignite persistence configuration.
DataStorageConfiguration storageCfg = new DataStorageConfiguration();
storageCfg.setStoragePath("ignitedb/storage");
storageCfg.setWalPath("ignitedb/wal");
storageCfg.setWalArchivePath("ignitedb/wal/archive");

// Enabling the persistence.

storageCfg.getDefaultDataRegionConfiguration().setPersistenceEnabled(true);

// Applying settings.
cfg.setDataStorageConfiguration(storageCfg);

Ignite ignite = Ignition.getOrStart(cfg);
ignite.active(true);
// Get all server nodes that are already up and running.
Collection<ClusterNode> nodes = ignite.cluster().forServers().nodes();
// Set the baseline topology that is represented by these nodes.
ignite.cluster().setBaselineTopology(nodes);
return ignite;
```

The cache is created like this:

```
cacheConfiguration = new CacheConfiguration<>();
cacheConfiguration.setBackups(1);
cacheConfiguration.setAtomicityMode(CacheAtomicityMode.ATOMIC);
cacheConfiguration.setName("UserCache");
cacheConfiguration.setCacheMode(CacheMode.LOCAL);
cacheConfiguration.setReadFromBackup(true);
cacheConfiguration.setWriteSynchronizationMode(CacheWriteSynchronizationMode.FULL_SYNC);
cacheConfiguration.setIndexedTypes(String.class, User.class);
IgniteCache<String, User> cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(cacheConfiguration);
```

Storing `User` objects in the cache works. Ignite creates a directory structure under `C:\ignite`. But on app restart, all data is lost. How can I configure this properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the root cause is `LOCAL` cache mode. Try to use `REPLICATED` or `PARTITIONED`: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cache-modes

Comment: Apparently LOCAL caches don't support native persistence, even though it isn't documented anywhere and no meaningful error is thrown when one tries to create one (although I see some errors in the logs the first time a persistent LOCAL cache is created).

Comment: This was a step in the right direction. I see that now there is some data in *.wal files in my ignite directory. But the data isn't loaded when the application restarts...